# Collectionview doesn't show anything during runtime

Tags: iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return getName.count;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[getName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

When I run the app then it doesn't show anything.what are the reasons behinds that

Comment: maybe getName.count it gives 0.

Comment: No i check it give correct output

Comment: once check, it seems to be you are not adding imageview to your collection view's cell.

Comment: the exception line is::::    ImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[getName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

Comment: [UICollectionViewCell setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8f80780
2014-09-16 12:16:36.599 CollectionView[1013:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICollectionViewCell setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8f80780'

Comment: here recipeImageView converted into UICollectionViewCell ,may be problem with tag value

Comment: No tag is rightly set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly its tag issue cause as per your crash log

[UICollectionViewCell setImage:] means image is directly set to UICollectionViewCell not recipeImageView. so you have to check proper tag value.. 
so ones check tag value of image view..

otherwise check that you have register your collection view cell.